# Перенаправить пользователя по intent в настройки телефона

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения

Требуется из мобильного приложения перенаправить пользователя по намерению (intent) на страницу с настройками (контроль фоновой активности). Чтобы пользователь перейдя на экран сразу смог выбрать нужный режим.
[image: экран куда требуется перевести пользователя]